# Conditional expectation of dependent variable provided relationship

Tags: self-study, random-variable, conditional-expectation, joint-distribution, dependent-variable

Suppose I have two random variables, $X$ with PDF $f_X$, and $Y$. Moreover, I know that $Y = h(X)$, and I do know the $h(x)$. Now I want to calculate the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$:
$$
E[Y|X] = E[h(X)|X = x] = E[h(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x) f_X(x)dx
$$

Is that correct, that despite not knowing the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$, I can still calculate the *conditional* expectation of random variable $Y$?

Comment: It seems to me things are much simpler than that, if $h(X)$ represents a deterministic function. In that case, $E[Y|X=x]=h(x)$. Thus, it seems you mean that $h(X)$ is a one-parameter distribution: is it correct?

Comment: You are right, it was much simpler than that. For example, I could have had X ~ N(0, 1) and Y = sin(X).

Comment: Then I would say that your formula is correct. However, I don't understand why you say that you don't know the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$: you know the conditional one for any value of $X$ and the marginal one of $X$, thus I'd say you can derive it.

Comment: Your first equality is just wrong.  In general $E[Y|X] \neq E[Y|X = x]$, because $E[Y|X]$ is a **random variable** (more specifically, a function of $X$, say $g(X)$ -- but it is still a random variable), while $E[Y|X = x]$ is a **fixed real value** (more specifically, it equals to $g(x)$, i.e., the value of $g(X)$ evaluated at the set $\{\omega: X(\omega) = x\}$, which happens to be $g(x)$).

Comment: If you know $Y = h(X)$, then $E[Y|X] = E[h(X)|X] = h(X)$, by the very basic property of conditional expectation ("take out what is known").  There is no need to bring pdf $f_X$ into the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Since $Y$ is a function of $h(X)$ then in your case you have some 'knowledge' on $Y$, hence it would not be extraordinary to be able to calculate the conditional expectation of $Y$, because it is equivalent to calculating the conditional expectation of a function of $X$, in your case $h(X)$